# JQuery (1.10.2) overrides click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, joomla

Hey I have an html page working perfectly, and its a bootstrap web-page.

I'm trying to convert this design to Joomla(CMS) design,

I have a problem that there is a JQuery function overrides menu elements click.

So if I clicked any menu element it will do nothing!

this is the button code :

```
<li class="item-101"><a class="scroll-link selected" href="/joomlaExample/">home</a></li>
```

after the tracing I found that this function is what making this problem :

```
r.handler && (c = r, r = c.handler, a = c.selector), r.guid || (r.guid = x.guid++), (l = v.events) || (l = v.events = {}), (f = v.handle) || (f = v.handle = function (e) {
                return typeof x === i || e && x.event.triggered === e.type ? t : x.event.dispatch.apply(f.elem, arguments)
            }, f.elem = e), n = (n || "").match(T) || [""], u = n.length;
```

But when I remove the function my page don't work as it was suppose to be =(

and I have no Idea what this function mean or what it dose.

Please help me.

UPDATE:

this is the block that the function is in :

```
function at() {
    try {
        return a.activeElement
    } catch (e) {}
}
x.event = {
    global: {},
    add: function (e, n, r, o, a) {
        var s, l, u, c, p, f, d, h, g, m, y, v = x._data(e);
        if (v) {
              r.handler && (c = r, r = c.handler, a = c.selector), r.guid || (r.guid = x.guid++), (l = v.events) || (l = v.events = {}), (f = v.handle) || (f = v.handle = function (e) {
                return typeof x === i || e && x.event.triggered === e.type ? t : x.event.dispatch.apply(f.elem, arguments)
            }, f.elem = e), n = (n || "").match(T) || [""], u = n.length;
            while (u--) s = rt.exec(n[u]) || [], g = y = s[1], m = (s[2] || "").split(".").sort(), g && (p = x.event.special[g] || {}, g = (a ? p.delegateType : p.bindType) || g, p = x.event.special[g] || {}, d = x.extend({
                type: g,
                origType: y,
                data: o,
                handler: r,
                guid: r.guid,
                selector: a,
                needsContext: a && x.expr.match.needsContext.test(a),
                namespace: m.join(".")
            }, c), (h = l[g]) || (h = l[g] = [], h.delegateCount = 0, p.setup && p.setup.call(e, o, m, f) !== !1 || (e.addEventListener ? e.addEventListener(g, f, !1) : e.attachEvent && e.attachEvent("on" + g, f))), p.add && (p.add.call(e, d), d.handler.guid || (d.handler.guid = r.guid)), a ? h.splice(h.delegateCount++, 0, d) : h.push(d), x.event.global[g] = !0);
            e = null
        }
    },
```

there are more to this block but its more than 1000 line! 
if you have the file JQuery(1.10.2) its at line 1616.

Comment: How did you find out that this is the piece of code that is causing your problem?

Comment: @tlindell from the Developers tool on Chrome (F12), I found the button then locked under "event listener" then "click".

Comment: The script looks obfuscated, like it has been through a program to condense the code. The variables are single letters that is why I think that. You could try and find a beautifier for your code to see of that helps clear up this mess. I can see where it is adding a function to given elements but I cannot tell which ones it is giving them to. I can see in the bottom where it is listening for an event, but I cannot tell which event it is listening for.

Comment: I wonder if you tried to either remove your current line of code that installs jquery 10 to your site and tried a different version of jquery, if that would work

Comment: @tlindell This code is after beautification (if that's a word), it was a one line code!, I don't know what to do =(.

Comment: @tlindell I didn't because the design uses this version, and I'm afraid that if I changed it, it won't work

Comment: It is easy enough to remove one line of code from the head section declaring the jquery version and put in a new one just to try it out. Does the cms you are using let you do that?

Comment: Are you sure it's actually jQuery causing the problem? I used jQuery 1.10.2 when it was the latest version on loads of sites I've developed and never had this type of problem. I think something else is the issue here.